# visual studio 2013 mvc 5 configuration initial user secret

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new for 2013 MVC 5.  I am trying to initial an user in seed of the configuration.  However I don't not how to encrypt the secret in the

> context.Secrets.AddOrUpdate( i => i.UserName, new UserSecret {"admin",
>   "encrtpted-secret"} );

Does any one know how?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to add the secret via the UserSecretStore.Create method as that will hash the password.  Unfortunately this is internal right now so there's not a great way for you to access the hash/validate methods directly as its intended that you access this functionality via the Store interface.